# Is it possible to have multiple passport.js authentication in the same app?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

What I'm trying to build is a Node.js app that has 2 different registration forms and login forms. One is for a business side and the other is for a client side.

I'm trying to use passport.js to authenticate the users but how do I distinguish between the two logins in the same Node.js app?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do this. Read the passport npm documentation.